# How to use FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) while making build of expo react native app through eas cli

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I had expo sdk less than sdk 45 in my expo react native app which previously used expo cli. For using FCM, I used to write **expo push:android:upload --api-key** , in which your token means server key. But now, my app has been converted to eas cli and I can't find the command or procedure to use FCM for notifications in my app anywhere not even in expo documentation. I previously used to follow this guide
[enter link description here](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/using-fcm/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `eas credentials`, select Android, then Push Notifications: Manage your FCM Api Key, and then choose the appropriate option to set up the key.
[docs...](https://docs.expo.dev/app-signing/managed-credentials/#android)

**OR**

1. Go to https://expo.dev/
2. Select a project
3. Go to credentials
4. Click on the application ID
5. In the Service Credentials section, add FCM Server Key

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helped me but I still have a confusion that how should I place google-services.json now in my project. Previously, I used to place it in the root folder because after adding FCM key, I'm still not able to get notifications on app

Comment: I also put it in the root directory, in app.json in the android section, add the line `googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json"`. Then you just need to build a new version or a dev client (notifications do not work on emulators!)

Comment: You can look at the build log to make sure that the file was added without errors.
In the "Run gradlew" section there will be a similar line:
> Task :app:processReleaseGoogleServices
Parsing json file: .../android/app/google-services.json

Comment: Do you have any idea about this error
" Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/home/expo/workingdir/build'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':expo-error-recovery:writeReleaseAarMetadata' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed."
I don't seem to understand this. This is the error I saw in Run gradlew

Comment: These are warnings, they do not affect your application, don't worry